# XSLT fetching nodes with a specific child value

Tags: xml, xslt

```
  <xxx>
      <EntityOverview>
        <LevelId>7</LevelId>
        <LongName>trombone</LongName>
      </EntityOverview>
      <EntityOverview>
        <LevelId>10</LevelId>
        <LongName>bananaphone</LongName>
      </EntityOverview>
    </xxx>
```

I want to fetch for example the data of LevelId 10 then LevelId 7 to get something like this:

10 bananaphone
7 trombone

Any idea on how to write the XSLT? Im starting to learn

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to process elements in a different order than giving in the document then you have to apply-templates in the order you want, for instance

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//EntityOverview[LevelId = 10]"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//EntityOverview[LevelId = 7"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Or you can sort on the `LevelId` e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//EntityOverview">
    <xsl:sort select="LevelId" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

With XSLT 2.0 you can write stuff in a more compact form:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//EntityOverview[LevelId = 10], //EntityOverview[LevelId = 7"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this? (provided xxx is the root element)

```
<xsl:template match="//xxx/EntityOverview">
    <xsl:value-of select="LevelId"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="LongName"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>  
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: thank you but how can I specify I want the LevelId 10 for example?